# Unable to stream song using Soundcloud JS api

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am using soundcloud to stream songs. But I don't know why songs are not playing.

Here is the [Full Code](http://pastebin.com/yXVn3yJU)

Inside Button click I am having this function, this function is given in the [soundcloud docs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#streaming)

```
SC.stream('/tracks/TRACK_ID').then(function(sound){
   console.log(sound);   //this outputs 
   sound.play();        // this does not do anything
});
```

json_object is returned in the console which is like this

`t.exports {options: Object, controller: null, streamInfo: null, _registerPlays: true, _errorRecoveryCounts: 0…}`

What must be the problem in the code? Why Song is not playing?

Comment: Could be browser specific, have you tried different browsers? Check the developer tools console for errors - an error may help you solve this riddle

Comment: @JaromandaX Question updated. Both functions works same as given by soundcloud docs.

Comment: `json_object is returned in the console` - do you mean `the output of console.log(sound) is ...` - that output does not look like it could be the output of that console.log by the way, are you sure that's right?

Comment: there's other problems with your code - you may end up with multiple elements with the same id - which will break things

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes I got to know the problem of id and I am now added `id` dynamically. And yes the console output is same what I have posted above.

Comment: and that is the exact output of that console.log? including the trailing ...

Comment: @JaromandaX It contains further fields also

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it's been a long time since I've worked with the API so I'm not sure if this'll help but I made something about a year ago [which animates the speaker using tracks from Soundcloud](http://donniedamato.info/soundcloud/).  You can look at the source and I think the part that may be relevant to you could be this:

```
var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('sc-widget'));

function playStereo(){
    widget.getCurrentSound(function(sound){
    if(sound != null){
        widget.play();
    } else {
        widget.pause();
    }
};
```